# Angular - Meteor subscribe/collection

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I am new to Metoer and I have two dumb questions related to the meteor collection and the subscribe.

1) I understand that if I subscribed to a collection in one of my controllers, and it will load the data into my local collection and be persistent until I stop the subscription. my question is what if I have different views which need to access the same collection but the views are independent of each other which means, user can access any of the views without accessing the others first.

For example, if I have view to display all parties hosted by current user and all parties hosted by other users. What is the best way to subscribe it? I originally thought I can just subscribe in one controller to get all documents and do the filtering in the collection selector. But this won't work as user can access any of the views first. so I ended up subscribe to it in the two controllers. Is this the right thing to do?

```
$meteor.subscribe('parties').then(function(){
      ....
 });

$scope.parties= $meteor.collection(function(){
     return Parties.find({// select either my parties or others' parties});
});
```

2) My second question is that if I have a list view and a details view,  I am trying to access the object in the details view's controller.

```
$scope.party = $meteor.object(Parties, $stateParams.partyId);
```

This works fine if I click the details button from the list view as the list view's controller has subscribed to all the documents.

However if user refresh the page from browser (which is not intended in a meteor app but we cannot stop users from doing that )? the object won't be accessible.
How can we deal with this in a Meteor app? I don't want to subscribe it again in details view even that will solve the problem.